# UIAlertView issue with session.dataTaskWithRequest

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have this code that verifies IAP receipts and Im trying to show an alert based on what status this function is returned with but I keep getting this error

```
"This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release. ....... ( then a whole list of numbers and stuff)"
```

This is the code Im using, (pretty simplified). Im guessing it has something to do with threads and asynchronus stuff that Im not really too sure about. How do I do this the right way?

```
 func verifyPaymentReceipt(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction, completion : (status : Bool) -> ()) {

 .... //Verify Receipt code

 let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(storeRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error  in

    if(error != nil){
      //Handle Error
    }
    else{
      completion(status: true)
    }

}
```

And this is how I am calling the function :

```
verifyPaymentReceipt(transaction, completion: { (status) -> () in
                        if status {
                            print("Success")
                            self.showMessage(true)
                        } else {
                            print("Fail")
                            self.showMessage(false)
                        }
                    })
```

And this is the show message function

```
    func showMessage(message: Bool) {

    var alert = UIAlertView()
    if message == true {
        alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "Your purchase(s) are succeessful", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
    } else {
        alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "Your purchase(s) restore failed, Please try again.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
    }
    alert.show()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your `showMessage()` routine to jump back onto the main thread:

```
func showMessage(message: Bool) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        var alert = UIAlertView()
        if message == true {
            alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "Your purchase(s) are succeessful", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
        } else {
            alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "Your purchase(s) restore failed, Please try again.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
        }
        alert.show()
    })
}
```

Although you probably also want to update to use `UIAlertController` instead of `UIAlertView`, which has been deprecated. Unless you still need to support iOS 7.

Or you could put this line into `verifyPaymentReceipt()` instead, so that anything you do from there gets back to the main thread. Both are acceptable options.

Comment: Yes I am aware that `UIAlertView` is deprecated. (Hard not to know when that yellow exclamation mark constantly reminds you), but thanks anyway! Where is the ideal place to add it? Would it right after the `verifyPaymentReceipt()` function call or should it be after `task`?

Comment: That depends on which block is running in a background thread. You can find that by adding a breakpoint and looking at the thread number in the debug navigation list on the left when you hit it.

Comment: Thanks! I am learning programming by myself and this is my first app. People like you are giving me alot of needed guidance and I really appreciate it. Thanks!!